# Is there a way to change the URL from an iframe with Livewire?

Tags: javascript, laravel-livewire

So far, this is my solution, and it works, but I think its a bit dirty...

I have a select that uses `symbol` variable to show a chart on an iframe:

```
      <select
        wire:model="symbol"
        id="symbol"
        class="w-full px-2 py-1 rounded-md"
        onchange="changeSymbol()"
        >
```

The chart URL is something as: `/chart/SYMBOL_VALUE`

So far, I haven't been able to alter the URL using Livewire (using the `wire:model` and a `updatedSymbol()` function), so I had to use that `changeSymbol()` javascript function, that goes like:

```
<script>
  const changeSymbol = () => {
    const sym = document.getElementById("symbol").value
    const graf = document.getElementById("graf")
    graf.innerHTML = `<iframe
      src="/chart/${sym}"
      height="100%"
      width="100%"
      ></iframe>
    `
  }
</script>
```

Yeah... sure, this works, but I don't *like it*, it looks to me as a patchy solution. Is there a way to change the URL of an iframe inside livewire, and make it to load the inner page you want?

Comment: Are you able to select the iframe with a query selector?

Comment: <iframe id="xxx">?

Comment: Yeah, I think so

Comment: Why not just do `document.getElementById("xxx").src = 'new source'`?

Comment: Using JavaScript, yeah it will work too, but I'm looking for a way to do it using only Livewire, if possible

Comment: Oh! I just have an idea based on your suggestion, I'll check!